# How to account for an ignore list of words in the following regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex expression that breaks text into sentences. However the regex messes up with abbreviations like "i.e.". Is there a way to ignore lets say a list of abbreviations?

What I have:

```
 $sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])/i', $string);
```

This works great with normal strings however if one is using text that has "i.e.", it splits it at the period. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a sample `$string`? Maybe `(i\.e\.|otherabbreviations) (*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])`.

Comment: Splitting text into words, punctuations characters or sentences isn't a thing you can do easily with a simple pattern. To be clear, PHP isn't the language to do that. It's better to use Python or Java (and probably Perl) that have modules available for this kind of tasks. You need also already trained dictionaries. Search about **nlp** and **nltk** in your favorite search engine (duckduckgo for sure), otherwise all you will do will be a poor DIY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
(?<=(?<!\b(?:[i\.e\.])\b)[.!?])\s+(?=[\w])
```